# In Android,How to get current Location and getting the registered user location within 3km or 5km distance?

Tags: android, database, location

I am new to android, can anyone help me for my question.... How to get current Location and getting the registered user's location available within 3km or 5km distance??????

It's like a Find Taxi to show the user location nearby the taxi available.
I can get current location by using this code.

```
// Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Getting Current Location From GPS
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if(location!=null){
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
             locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
              final LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " "+latLng, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    mLongitude = location.getLongitude();

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}
```

Comment: You can do that by sending user current location constantly to server and then server will have list of all users near by you and you have to make just request to get that list..!!

Comment: How do you get the location of taxis to check with the user location?

Comment: I also have the same question.... how to get location of a car or taxi within the user location exactly 1 to 3 KM ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `distanceBetween` method as it sounds like you already have the coordinates and that's all you need with this method: 
[Location.distanceBetween() Javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html)

This [link](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) might be helpful to you, as it details the use of the Haversine formula to calculate the distance.

Excerpt:

This script [in Javascript] calculates great-circle distances between the two points – that is, the shortest distance over the earth’s surface – using the ‘***Haversine***’ formula.

Use [geocoder.getFromLocationName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocationName%28java.lang.String,%20int%29.html), you get back a list of Address objects, in those objects you will find all the information you need about the location.

To test this on the simulator you need an image with the Google APIs included. In a device should be fine if you have the market installed.

There are two steps to this:

Get the current location - latitude & longitude, using the GPS, network, last-known location etc. The Android [location documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) includes sample code.

Use the Android [Geocoder class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) to request a lookup to convert the lat/long to an Address (from which you can easily extract city, country, street, etc). Specifically, you need to use the getFromLocation() method